# handsontable propToCol returns property not column number

Tags: handsontable

I'm trying to use **propToCol** method in my handsontable grid. However, that method, which is supposed to return an integer is returning a **string value of the property name** instead if i try to alert the value of
`#("grid").handsontable(propToCol ,prop);`
How do I get the column number in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the problem and fixed the issue. I was using that method on a property that I was not displaying in the table(**`hidden property`**).So the propToCol method was not returning the  column number.I put a check to ensure that that method is only applied to the properties i display in the handsontable grid.So it seems to work now.